# can we override alloc and dealloc in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, overriding, dealloc, alloc

I know that this is rarely required to override the `alloc` or `dealloc` methods,but if required is it possible in iPhone programming?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can and indeed, you should (if using manual memory management) override `dealloc` to release any resources you hold (not forgetting to call `[super dealloc]` when finished). Overriding `alloc` is possible but, as you say, rarely needed.

Comment: A couple of notes: subclasses of `NSObject` should override `allocWithZone:` rather than `alloc`, and can't override `dealloc` in code that's compiled with ARC.

Comment: Correction: I should have said, "code compiled for ARC can't call `[super dealloc]`". It's still possible to override dealloc, but rarely useful.

Comment: overriding `dealloc` is still a good practice in case you need to unregister from notifications or remove gesture recognizers when the instance is about to be deallocated.

Comment: Unregister from notifications and mark yourself as no longer the delegate for whatever you were the delegate for.  But, yes, in ARC, you can't call `[super dealloc]` or, more importantly, you don't need to, as ARC is "all over it" on your behalf.

Answer (score 6):

In general, overriding `alloc` is only done when you wish to, eg, allocate an object from a pool of available instances, or perhaps allocate a variable amount of storage for the object based on some external parameter.  (In C++ you can access the `new` parameters and allocate based on them, but Objective-C does not give you access to the `initXXX` parameters.)

I've never attempted any of this, and I suspect that its a bit of a minefield -- you need to study up on the structures and be pretty careful.

As Adam said, you should ALWAYS (in a reference counted environment) override `dealloc` if there are any retained objects held by your object.

**Update:**  An interesting thing you can do ... in RedClass or a superclass of it code something like:

```
+(id)alloc {
    if (self == [RedClass class]) {
        return [BlueClass alloc];
    }
    else {
        return [super alloc];
    }
}
```

The net result is that whenever you execute `[RedClass alloc]` a BlueCLass object will be returned.  (NB: Presumably BlueClass is a subclass of RedClass, or things will get seriously mucked up shortly after the object is returned.)

Not saying that it's a good idea to do this, but it's possible (and I don't offhand know of any cases where it wouldn't work reliably for vanilla user-defined classes).  And it does have a few possible uses.

**Additional note:** In some cases one might want to use `[self isSubclassOf:[RedClass class]]` rather than `==` (though that has some serious pitfalls).

Comment: "Objective-C does not give you access to the initXXX parameters." Huh?

Comment: Objective-C doesn't prevent you from accessing anything related to `alloc`, but there *are* no parameters to `alloc` (other than `self` and `_cmd`), so it's not clear what you're referring to. If you meant information about instances, for example their size, the Objective-C runtime gives you access to anything and everything an implementor would need to know.

Comment: Right, there are no parameters to alloc.  But C++ allows the alloc routine to access the `new` parameters.

Comment: @HotLicks, that's because -- as commonly used -- C++ does not make a clean distinction between allocation and initialization steps. Closest one could get is malloc()ing, memset()ting to zero, and then calling a standalone init() method.

Comment: What about objects like `NSNumber` that have a pool of instances for common values? I understand how `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` etc would work since we get the param before we alloc, but how does it know to return the same instance with `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1]`? Even with tagged pointers or all the other fancy stuff they do behind the scenes, you're still calling alloc first without any knowledge of the stored value. The only thing I can think is that calling `[NSNumber alloc]` returns a single shared instance and then `-[NSNumber initWith...]` returns the specific one. Yeah?

Comment: Wicked awesome... Just as I thought. `[NSNumber alloc]` returns a shared instance of `NSPlaceholderNumber`. `+[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]` returns a tagged pointer so it's the same no matter how many times you call it. `-[NSNumber initWithInt:100]` returns the same tagged pointer.

Comment: @JackLawrence -- Yep, in that case NSNumber alloc returns a dummy, and the init routine does all the work, allocating a new number instance if needed.  Which is why your init routine should always use the `self` value returned from the super's `init` routine, vs the value it received on the call.

Comment: @IvanVučica -- C++ *does* support what amounts to a stand-alone `alloc` routine, it's just rarely explicitly used.  However, I forget the syntax.

Comment: @HotLicks That's why I said "commonly". You could definitely just use `malloc(sizeof(TheClass))` (or `new` with a `char` array, then casting it), but it's simply not done. If there's a specialized syntax which would also allow allocation without initialization on the stack instead of heap, I'd appreciate it if you'd post it if you remember it.

Comment: @IvanVučica -- IIRC, the syntax is to define a `new` method on your class.  The first parm is the size to be allocated, and you may optionally mirror the constructor parms as additional parms to `new`.  (But I'm recalling this from about 12 years back, so it's a little fuzzy.)

Comment: @HotLicks Overriding the `new` operator?! That's nasty.  o_o  It also still requires a `malloc()` inside, and it still invokes the constructor. At least from what I can tell. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html Looks like invoking only `operator new` is supported, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382930/c-allocate-block-of-t-without-calling-constructor

Comment: @IvanVučica -- Like I said, I'm a bit vague on the details.  But the function is there and it (very crudely) mirrors `alloc`.  I used it to good effect when designing a set of sparse vector classes for data flow analysis.